# Arguments to callback function in mongoose, express and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, express, mongoose

I follow a MCV approach to develop my application. I encounter a problem that I dont know how the arguments are passed to the callback function.

animal.js (model)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema

var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });
animalSchema.statics = {
     list: function(cb) {
         this.find().exec(cb)
     }
}
mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema)
```

animals.js (controller)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Animal = mongoose.model('Animal')

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    Animal.list(function(err, animals) {
        if (err) return res.render('500')
        console.log(animals)
    }
}
```

Here comes my question: Why can the "list" in the model just execute callback without passing any argument? Where do the err and animals come from actually?

I think I may miss some concepts related to callback in node.js and mongoose. Thanks a lot if you can provide some explanation or point me to some materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function list wants to have a callback function passed.

So you pass a callback function.

`this.find().exec(cb)` wants a callback function too, so we pass the callback we got from the `list` function.

The `execute` function then calls the callback (executes it) with the parameters `err` and the object it received, in this case `animals`.

Inside of the list function happens something like `return callback(err, objects)` what is finally calling the callback function.

The callback function you passed now has got two parameters. These are `err` and `animals`

The key is : The callback function is passed as a parameter, but is never called until it is called by the `exec`. This function is calling it with parameters which are mapped to `err` and `animals`

EDIT:

As it seams unclear i will do a short example:

```
var exec = function (callback) {
    // Here happens a asynchronous query (not in this case, but a database would be)
    var error = null;
    var result = "I am an elephant from the database";
    return callback(error, result);
};

var link = function (callback) {
    // Passing the callback to another function 
    exec(callback);
};

link(function (err, animals) {
    if (!err) {
        alert(animals);
    }
});
```

Can be found as a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/yJWmy/

Comment: Thanks for answer first. I understand the first part of your answer. But I am confused with the second part: The list function never declare a variable called "animals". How does it map the object it received from the database to "animals"?

Comment: it doesnt have to know the name of the object, it simply calls `callback(err, objects)`which is mapped to `function (err, animals)` . So objects gets mapped to animals

Comment: Maybe you missed that callback is passed to the list function too, the execution happens inside of the list function, you can't see here

Comment: Am I correct to think this way?: when the "list" function inside "animal.js" runs this line `this.find().exec(cb)`, `this.find()` returns two variables "err" and "objects" and calls `cb(err, objects)`. So it maps to `function(XXX, YYY)` which is function(err, animals) in this case.

Comment: It causes my confusion because from the API doc of mongoose [Mongoose exec API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) , it does not mention how `err` and `objects` are passed to the callback function

Comment: Exec executes the query. A query calls a passed function with err and then the object the query resulted in

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. It is not easy to spot that the original code is doing similar like `return callback(error, result);` from the API doc. Your example illustrates very clearly.