# What parameters are passed to Mongoose callbacks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) it frequently lists an optional callback for certain query operators (like `findOneAndUpdate`), however, it does not mention what parameters (arguments) the callback takes. What are they, and how would I find out?

Also, if `conditions`, `update` etc. are optional, and I want to specify a callback at the end, do I have to pass in the `null` value, or empty objects or can I just specify the callback -- and hose does Mongoose know?

`Model.findOneAndUpdate([conditions], [update], [options], [callback])`

Comment: I am not sure. But may be the following is useful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266162/arguments-to-callback-function-in-mongoose-express-and-node-js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For nearly all [mongoose queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) the provided `callback` function will be called with two arguments in the [node callback pattern](http://thenodeway.io/posts/understanding-error-first-callbacks/) `callback(err, results)` as stated in the documentation:

> Anywhere a callback is passed to a query in Mongoose, the callback follows the pattern `callback(error, results)`. What results is depends on the operation: For `findOne()` it is a [potentially-null single document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne), `find()` a [list of documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), `count()` the [number of documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count), `update()` the [number of documents affected](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update), etc. The [API docs for Models](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model-js) provide more detail on what is passed to the callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

By default you can get two parameters in the callback function: `err` and `results`. The first one contains any errors that occurred during the runtime and the second has the old value of document. However you can get other variables in the callback parameters if you set some options in the `findOneAndUpdate` method. Let's see this with an example:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: id_var },
    { $set: { name: name_var } },
    {new: true, passRawResult: true},
    (err, doc, raw) => { /*Do something here*/ })
```

In this case, the `new: true` option indicates that the doc variable contains the new updated object. The `passRawResult: true` option indicates that you can get the raw result of the MongoDB driver as the third callback parameter. The raw parameter contains the result of the update, something like this:

```
"raw": {
    "lastErrorObject": {
      "updatedExisting": true,
      "n": 1
    },
    "value": { /*the result object goes here*/},
    "ok": 1,
    "_kareemIgnore": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the official mongoose documentation you can call findOneAndUpdate like this

```
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback) // executes
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options)  // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback) // executes
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update)           // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(update, callback)             // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(update)                       // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(callback)                     // executes
query.findOneAndUpdate()                             // returns Query
```

So you can just pass your callback, no need to pass null for other parameters

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate